# Change image organisation on image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an image slideshow as following:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0% 0%;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Very Simple Slider</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
  <div id="slider">
    <a href="#" class="control_next"></a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/e3bb/f/2012/155/0/c/naruto_unleashed_by_sketch_gfx-d529cho.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://assets.rbl.ms/6450955/980x.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://tampascene.com/images/new-images/parks-weedonisland.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_option"> </div>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

I would like to re-arrange the images as follows:
[image]

I have tried including more images into the  and the images end up glitching and not working I have also tried reducing the size but they still appear in different views if anyone has any pointers or ideas please just let me know.

If you could show me how to amend this it would be great I don't mind if it's in JS or CSS as long as it gets the job done I will greatly appreciate it.

And if this question needs improving it wouldn't hurt just trying to tell me instead of just downvoting I am only 13 years and still learning Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made some changes in javascript and css especially in width and height.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: parseInt(slideWidth) * 3 +"px",
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li img{
  max-width:100%;
  line-height: 0;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0% 0%;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Very Simple Slider</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
  <div id="slider">
    <a href="#" class="control_next"></a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/e3bb/f/2012/155/0/c/naruto_unleashed_by_sketch_gfx-d529cho.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://assets.rbl.ms/6450955/980x.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://tampascene.com/images/new-images/parks-weedonisland.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_option"> </div>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```